# How to show two semigroups are isomorphic?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

I have two finite semigroups namely $$S_1=\langle a,b: R\rangle,~~~S_2=\langle a,b: T\rangle$$ How can one show they are the same isomorphically? Should I show that the relations in one, implies  the others and vice versa? Thanks for your time and your consideration.

Comment: If you know that they are finite you can compute the multiplication tables and search for isomorphisms. I am not sure how computationally feasible this is.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: That's right. It is a practical method of using the Cayley table of them to find that possible isomorphism. But in this case, elements may exceed and so I am searching for an abstract way counting on theorems and facts. Regards

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I could find almost nothing on the web about it. Maybe it is covered inside an  old article or new one and so I am not aware of it.

Comment: Computationally, group isomorphism is already not so easy. I would guess semigroup isomorphism is more difficult.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thanks anyway fr your time. Am I allowed to send an email to you about an article?

Comment: If you wish. I don't claim to be able to respond right away

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: It's not clear to me that you can efficiently check isomorphy after computing the multiplication table. If your semigroups have many isomorphic subsemigroups, then a branch and cut approach will only work for very small semigroups.

Comment: @Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta I agree efficiency might be a big problem.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: semigroup isomorphism from multiplication tables is equivalent to graph isomorphism under polynomial time reductions. Suggests that it is hard in general, but perhaps good graph iso software (nauty, traces, bliss, conauto) could be of use for particular instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function $f_1 : S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ and can show that $f_1(u) = f_1(v)$ for all $(u, v) \in R$ then you will have shown that $f_1$ is a homomorphism. If you can find such a function $f_1$ and another function $f_2 : S_2 \rightarrow S_1$ such that $f_2(u) = f_2(v)$ for all $(u, v) \in T$ and additionally show that they are either (i) both injective or (ii) both surjective then you will have proved isomorphism.